# Add current_user Devise to Mongoid relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise, mongoid

Hi Guys I have a Relationships in Mongoid and I can not add current_user to this relation for get the user that create the deal. A relation with 3 model.

I have three models user.rb, house.rb and deal.rb

**user.rb** Relationships (devise model)

```
# Relationships
has_many :houses, dependent: :destroy
has_many :deals, dependent: :destroy
key :title
```

**house.rb**

```
# Relationships
 belongs_to :user
 embeds_many :deals
```

**deal.rb**

```
# Relationships
 embedded_in :house, :inverse_of => :deals
 belongs_to :user
```

In my **routes.rb**

```
 resources :houses do
  resources :deals
 end
```

In my houses_controller.rb in my create method I get current_user for each house of this side:

```
def create
   #@house = House.new(params[:house])
   @house = current_user.houses.new(params[:house])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @house.save
        format.html { redirect_to @house, notice: 'House was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @house, status: :created, location: @house }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @house.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In my **deals_controller.rb** I have the created method this:

```
    def create 
      @house = House.find_by_slug(params[:house_id])
      @user = User.find(:user_id)
      @deal = @house.deals.create!(params[:deal])
      redirect_to @house, :notice => "Comment created!" 
    end
```

**How I can add to this last method create, the current_user that created the deal?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add these two lines to the create action:

```
@deal.user=current_user
@deal.save
```

And I would also suggest you not to use create! instead you should use .new and .save like in the scaffolded create actions! ;)

Comment: Thank you! I have change create for new and save :D. However for "embeds_many :deals" in house.rb and "embedded_in :house, :inverse_of => :deals" in deal.rb, show the error "Referencing a(n) Deal document from the User document via a relational association is not allowed since the Deal is embedded." But with has_many and belongs_to working fine. Is best working with embeds_many or has_many and references? Thank you

Comment: If anybody comes across this, to avoid the error that @hyperrjas is seeing, ie "Referencing a(n) Deal document from the User document via a relational association is not allowed since the Deal is embedded." Just remove this line from the user.rb that he defined in his first question #has_many :deals, dependent: :destroy